# Alfresco CMIS: Retrieving relevant context when searching for content

Tags: alfresco, cmis, apache-chemistry

I am using Alfresco Community 201707 x64. My application is querying the repository via CMIS, using Apache Chemistry Open CMIS 1.1.

The question, as the title suggests, is: when querying the repository for document content (using the CONTAINS predicate on the search query), how do I retrieve a document's relevant context? Can I do it using CMIS, or do I have to use a different approach?

For example, in Alfresco Share, when a user searches the repository for documents containing some word, the relevant results are displayed with a snippet of the document's content with said word highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think this is available in CMIS, it is however generally available if using SOLR, depending on Alfresco version.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/search-api-highlight.html

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Lista,

It is a new feature coming with Alfresco 5.2.1 : http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/search-api-highlight.html

You can use it by making a call to the `/search` endpoint :

> The Search API provides access to the search features of Alfresco
>   Content Services.
>
> The Search API accepts POST requests containing JSON structures as
>   described in the table below. The JSON is structured to group options
>   related to different query concepts together.
>
> The Search API is defined under the search namespace. It uses the
>   /search endpoint, which does not accept any URL parameters and is
>   therefore, completely controlled via the parameters in a POST body.

But as far as I know, this is not possible to do it by CMIS. Can you switch the way you are interacting with Alfresco (the REST way) ?